# How to check Firestore reference existence using Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update data in Firestore being triggered by cloud Functions.

Using Admin SDK, I checked reference path like this below.
Not working well.

```
export const userProfileUpdate = functions
  .firestore.document("/users/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId
    const afterData = change.after.data()
    const username = afterData["username"]

   if (!afterData.exists) {
      // nothing to do
      return
   }
   const infoRef = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("infos")
      .doc(userId)

    const infoDoc = await infoRef.get()

    if (infoDoc.exists) {
      await infoRef.update({
        username: username})
    } 
}
```

In my app structure, it is possible Firestore reference path doesn't exist yet when update data in `infos`.
So I want to check the path before update.

I got the errors:

> Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string

in `const postRef = await admin.firestore().collection("posts").doc(userId)`.

How to check the Firestore reference existence using Firebase Admin SDK?

Adding to above scripts, I have to handle `userId`.
How to handle it?

I can't handle `userId` using `afterData.exists`.

Comment: If you `console.log(userId);` right before you use that value to access the database, what does it show?

Comment: As you said, the value is `undefined`. How do I check `userId`?  In this context, should I add `afterData.exists` ? Or should I define `const { before, after } = change ;  after.exists `.

Comment: I updated my question. How to handle `userId`

Comment: `if (context.params.userId !== undefined && context.params.userId !== null) { ... }`

Comment: Hi does my answer help? if yes acknowledge it and if not then we can solve it further

Comment: Thank you. I accepted `if (!context.params.userId) `. It did work well

Comment: @Takeshi glad to hear that the issue is resolved can u have a look at my updated answer ?

Comment: No need `!afterData` in If's condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was at this line

```
if (!afterData.exists) {
      // nothing to do
      return
   }
```

Here `.exist` does not exist on `admin.firestore.DocumentData` As afterData is of type `admin.firestore.DocumentData`.

I have recreated the issue at my end you just need to change some things but here’s the updated code just for sake of it :

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

export const userProfileUpdate = functions
    .firestore.document("/users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const afterData = change.after.data();
      const username = afterData["username"];
      console.log(userId);
      console.log(username);
      if (!userId) { // ⇐ notice
      // nothing to do
        return;
      }
      const infoRef = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("infos")
          .doc(userId);

      const infoDoc = await infoRef.get();

      if (infoDoc.exists) {
        console.log("infoDoc exists", infoDoc);
        await infoRef.update({
          username: username});
      }
    });
```

Reference : [firestore.DocumentBuilder.onUpdate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.firestore.documentbuilder.md#firestoredocumentbuilderonupdate)